# What does "id" in this Haskell code mean?

Tags: haskell

this question is from a Haskell newbie.

I write code below to check how many `True` in a list, and if it has `even` number of `True`, then return `True`, otherwise return `False'.

```
xor =
foldr xor' False
where
xor' True True = False
xor' False False = False
xor' _ _ = True
```

However, I found some code snippets below, and it seems that it can do the same thing.. 
Here is the code:

```
xor :: [Bool] -> Bool
xor = odd . length . filter id
```

But I just have no idea how `id` works in the above code, could anyone give me some help?

Comment: It is the identity function: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=id

Comment: `id` is just the identity function. `filter id` is the same as `filter (==True)` - it just removes the `False` elements.

Comment: I wonder who would downvote this perfectly good question (for a beginner) - guys we should keep the extremely positive Haskell subgroup friendly!

Comment: @Carsten, Thank you! I searched the meaning of `id` function. But what I was confused is why `id` can be used here. Now I understand it due to great answers below :)

Comment: @Carsten Yes, the Haskell community has a reputation for being [welcoming and friendly](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/geek-of-the-week/simon-peyton-jones-geek-of-the-week/) to maintain!

Comment: On an unrelated not, you can also define `xor` more concisely, and with less memory consumption as `xor = foldr1 (/=)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definition of `id` is `id x = x`, so `filter id` is the same as `filter (\x -> x)`. That is it takes all the elements of the list whose value is `True`.

Answer (score 11):

The `id` function is the identity function, with the very simple definition

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

The function `filter` has the type

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

It takes a function returning a boolean, applies that function to every element of the list and keeps all the elements for which the function returns `True`.  So when you have `filter id`, it filters the list returning all the elements equal to `True`.

Comment: Thank you bheklilr, you give me the correct response but I can only choose one as "answer". I somehow know `id`, it is like the `[]` for `function`. However, using it in this particular problem really blows my mind :)